# How to connect cookies to an unique user in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, widget

I'm creating a widget that keeps track on how many times a unique user visits my site. I started using cookies, but they keep track on how many times the site is being visited, and not how many times a unique user visits.

I've tried the following code.

```php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visits']))
{
    $cookie = 1;
    setcookie("visits", $cookie);
}
else
{
    $cookie = ++$_COOKIE['visits'];
    setcookie("visits", $cookie);
}

add_action("widgets_init", function() {
    register_widget("Visits_Count");
});

class Visits_Count extends WP_Widget {
    // Class constructor
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 
            'classname' => 'visits_count',
            'description' => 'This plugin will provide the total visits per user ',
        );
        parent::__construct( 'visits_count', 'Visits Count', $widget_ops );
    }

    // Output the widget content on the front-end
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        ?>
        <p>Total amount of visits: <?php echo $_COOKIE['visits'] ?></p>
        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Output the option form field in admin Widgets screen
    public function form( $instance ) {

    }

    // Save options
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    }
}
```

I want the widget to count the visits per unique user. Do you connect it with the database? If yes, how?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? plenty of plugins for that

Comment: We have to create this for a schoolproject :)

Comment: then yes, you need to connect to a database, wordpress has some build in functions for that